# Install Playn using Maven stops and does not finish

Tags: installation, playn

I have followed instructions exactly from http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted

I installed Git and put the playn-samples into a folder called C:\a2.
I set the environment variables to point to JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME.
I installed maven and made sure the version was greater than 3.0.3.
In windows command window I did:

```
cd C:\a2\playn-samples\showcase
mvn test
```

But it gave me this and pauses forever (I am a beginner to maven):

```
c:\a2\playn-samples\showcase>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] PlayN Showcase Metaproject
[INFO] PlayN Showcase Core
[INFO] PlayN Showcase Android
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PlayN Showcase Metaproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ playn-showcase --
-
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3/c
ommons-lang-2.3.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0
b4.jar
78 KB   151 KB
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a temporary network failure. I bet if you try it again it will eventually get all of the necessary dependencies downloaded.